# Bibliography Style: Author's first name as single letter

Tags: bibliographies

I want to generate the bibliography in which each author's first name is denoted by single letter and a number is given to every reference:

**Example:**

```
[1] P. Ackermann and M. Kreuzer. Grobner basis cryptosystems. Applicable Alg.
in Eng., Commun. and Comput., 17:173–194, 2006.
```

and **my code is**

```
% B I B L I O G R A P H Y
% -----------------------

% The following statement selects the style to use for references.  It controls the sort order of the entries in the bibliography and also the formatting for the in-text labels.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
% This specifies the location of the file containing the bibliographic information.
% It assumes you're using BibTeX (if not, why not?).
\cleardoublepage % This is needed if the book class is used, to place the anchor in the correct page,
                 % because the bibliography will start on its own page.
                 % Use \clearpage instead if the document class uses the "oneside" argument
\phantomsection  % With hyperref package, enables hyperlinking from the table of contents to bibliography
% The following statement causes the title "References" to be used for the bibliography section:
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}

% Add the References to the Table of Contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}

\bibliography{nu-ethesis}
```

and **reference code is **

```
@article{link:cac,
 title={A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key},
      author={Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
      journal={International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies},
      volume={1},
      number={5},
      pages={332--336},
      year={2010}
    }
```

and this will give reference as follow:
[image: Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGn6Z.png)![1]

Which package do I need to install to generate the auto bibliography like the example as mentioned above with line number and how?

**Note that**  my code use `chicaco` style and i want to change this and make my reference as quoted in example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may to try using the `abbrvnat` bibliography style (and the `natbib` citation management package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{link:cac,
 title   = {A comparison between public key authority and 
            certification authority for distribution of 
            public key},
 author  = {Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
 journal = {International Journal of Computer Science 
            and Information Technologies},
 volume  = {1},
 number  = {5},
 pages   = {332--336},
 year    = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{link:cac}, \cite{link:cac}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to write reference in this style as follow                                                                      A. Gaurav, and S. Singh. "A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key." International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies 1.5 (2010): 332-336.                                                          Can you help me which package i use to generate the following style as mentioned above? In this Example Author's first name Agarwal is represented with A

Comment: @user137359 - I am utterly confused now! Is "Gaurav" the given ("first") name or the surname? The input you provided, `author={Agarwal, Gaurav}` certainly gave the impression that "Gaurav" is the given ("first") name; however, your comments makes it look like "Gaurav" is the surname. Please clarify. Separately, while your write-up made it look like you did *not* want quotation marks around the publication's title, your follow-up comment makes it look like this formatting aspect is crucial. Please edit your posting to specify more clearly what you're looking for, in terms of formatting.

Comment: @Mico: My bad. I took it back.

Comment: @user137359 - The formatting requirements you stated in the posting -- Ackermann and M. Kreuzer. Grobner basis cryptosystems. Applicable Alg. in Eng., Commun. and Comput., 17:173–194, 2006. -- and in the follow-up comment -- A. Gaurav, and S. Singh. "A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key." International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies 1.5 (2010): 332-336 -- are rather different from each other. (For instance, note the positions of the `year` items.) Please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico: "Agarwal" is the first name of author. the code`author={Agarwal, Gaurav}` is copied from google scholar.

Comment: @user137359 - I must disagree with you. If the code is `author={Agarwal, Gaurav}`, BibTeX *must* parse "Agarwal" as the surname and "Gaurav" as the first name. FWIW, an Indian friend informs me that "Gaurav" is indeed a male first name in India and that "Agarwal" is a fairly common family name in India, esp. among Jains.

Comment: @Mico: I want to add comma  between author and article name instead of full stop. And also i want to write name of article in inverted commas (as `G. Agarwal and S. Sindh,"A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key". International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies.1(5):332--336,2010.`). Is there any way of writing such type of bibliography

Comment: @sam - All I can suggest at this point is that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the `custom-bib` package, and learn how to create a bibliography style file from scratch, a style file that incorporates all of your formatting requirements. Search this site for `makebst` and you'll find several postings related to how this utility should be used.